# how to block all tcp and udp and other protocol and only allow layer 2 communication?

Tags: firewall

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw default deny
sudo ufw allow XXXX
sudo ufw enable
```

1. Does `sudo ufw disable` block layer 2 by default?
2. How to block all TCP, UDP and other protocols, so only layer 2 communication is allowed?
3. How to drop a frame when layer 2 received frame size is greater than 64?

All these will be in dedicated line of ISP.

if using iptable, is below command correct?

```
iptables -N CHECK1
iptables -A INPUT -p all -m length --length 0
iptables -A CHECK1 -j DROP
```

or

```
// drop all 
iptables -N CHECK1
iptables -A INPUT -p all
iptables -A CHECK1 -j DROP
```

update:

iptable -p option do not have layer 2 after googled
how to drop frame over size 64?

should we consider size of tpacket_hdr as well?
32+64 = 96
because size of tpacket_hdr = 32

Comment: Why you not use iptables ?

Comment: i never configured firewall before, how to use iptables to do above?

Comment: -p option of iptables do not have layer 2, how to drop frame when size over 64, should we consider size of tpacket_hdr? so that the size allowed is 32+64 = 96, over 96 dropped?